# запуск консольного приложения через Bash скрипт и работать с ним итеративно input/ouput

Tags: bash

Добрый день, у меня есть **CLI** приложение, я его запускаю через **bash** команды и хочу внутри этого же *.sh* файла задавать команду для запущенного приложения, можете помочь советом как это осуществить?

Пример:

```
# test.sh файл
./app.sh
```

запускается **CLI** приложение и я хочу писать ему команды в этом же файле

Comment: ну так и пиши. в чём именно проблема-то?

Comment: что значит "задавать команду"?

Comment: у меня есть CLI версия телеграмм, я хочу запускать ее из bash файла и подавать на вход команды, исходя из ouput'a телеграмм приложения

Comment: вы хотите, что-то типа [`expect`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) -- это средство когда ничто другое не помогает. Если есть возможность, лучше явным API воспользоваться (для telegram для многих языков библиотеки существуют, к примеру, [Telethon на Питоне](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Telethon#running-telethon)).

Answer (score 0):

Тебе поможет комманда `read`, она призвана для того, чтобы принимать значения переменных в том числе и с клавиатуры.

[man read](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html) `read - Читает строку из стандартного ввода (или из файла)..`